# What is the proper way to cite a math textbook when writing a paper?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, reference-works

For example, I see this written in a bibliography of a paper:

W. Fulton and J. Harris, *Representation Theory, A First Course*, GTM-RIM 129, Springer, 1991.

The general case isn't clear to me from this example.

Comment: If it's in a journal, it depends on the journal. Otherwise it's just like citing any textbook. There are style guides.

Answer (score 0):

```
@BOOK(buell,
    AUTHOR= "D. A. Buell",
    TITLE = "Binary Quadratic Forms: Classical Theory and 
              Modern Computations", 
    PUBLISHER = "Springer-Verlag",
    YEAR = "1989"
    )

@BOOK(cox,
    AUTHOR= "D. A. Cox",
    TITLE = "Primes of the form \(x^2 + n y^2\)", 
    PUBLISHER = "John Wiley and Sons",
    YEAR = "1989"
    )


@BOOK(led:book,
    AUTHOR= "L. E. Dickson",
    TITLE = "Modern Elementary Theory of
              Numbers",
    PUBLISHER = "University of Chicago Press",
    YEAR = "1939"
    )


@BOOK(bj:book,
    AUTHOR= "B. W. Jones",
    TITLE = "The Arithmetic Theory of
              Quadratic Forms ",
    PUBLISHER = "Mathematical Association of America",
    YEAR = "1950",
    SERIES = "Carus Mathematical Monographs",
    NUMBER = "10"
    )

@BOOK(glw:book,
    AUTHOR= "G. L. Watson",
    TITLE = "Integral Quadratic Forms ", 
    PUBLISHER = "Cambridge University Press",
    SERIES = "Cambridge Tracts in Mathematics and Mathematical Physics",
    NUMBER = "51",
    YEAR = "1960"
    )


@BOOK(cassels,
    AUTHOR= "J.W.S. Cassels",
    TITLE = "Rational Quadratic Forms ", 
    PUBLISHER = "Academic Press",
    YEAR = "1978"
    )


@BOOK(jhc:book,
    AUTHOR= "J. H. Conway",
    TITLE = "The Sensual (Quadratic) Form",
    PUBLISHER = "The Mathematical Association of America",
    SERIES = "Carus Mathematical Monographs",
    NUMBER = "26",
    YEAR = "1997"
    )

@BOOK(conway:sloane,
    AUTHOR= "J. H. Conway  and N. J. A. Sloane",
    TITLE = "Sphere Packings, Lattices and Groups",
    PUBLISHER = "Springer-Verlag",
    EDITION = "{T}hird",
    YEAR = "1998"
    )




@BOOK(eichler,
    AUTHOR= "M. Eichler",
    TITLE = "Quadratische {F}ormen und orthogonale {G}ruppen", 
    PUBLISHER = "Springer-Verlag",
    YEAR = "1952"
    )
@BOOK(fk,
    AUTHOR= "R. Fricke and F. Klein",
    TITLE = "Vorlesungen {\"{u}}ber die Theorie der Automorphen Functionen",
    VOLUME = "1",
    PUBLISHER = "B. G. Teubner",
    YEAR = "1897"
    )

@BOOK(magnus,
    AUTHOR= "W. Magnus",
    TITLE = "Noneuclidean Tesselations and Their Groups",
    PUBLISHER = "Academic Press",
    YEAR = "1974"
    )

@BOOK(zagier,
    AUTHOR= "D. B. Zagier",
    TITLE = "Zetafunktionen und quadratischer K{\"{o}}rper",
    PUBLISHER = "Springer-Verlag",
    YEAR = "1981"
    )
@BOOK(kcg,
    AUTHOR= "M. Kuczma and B. Choczewski and R. Ger",
    TITLE = "Iterative Functional Equations",
    PUBLISHER = "Cambridge University Press",
    YEAR = "1990"
    )
@BOOK(nipp,
    AUTHOR= "G. L. Nipp",
    TITLE = "Quaternary Quadratic Forms: Computer Generated Tables", 
    PUBLISHER = "Springer-Verlag",
    YEAR = "1991"
    )
@BOOK(her:book,
    AUTHOR= "H. E. Rose",
    TITLE = "A Course in Number Theory", 
    PUBLISHER = "Oxford University Press",
    YEAR = "1988"
    )
@BOOK(wjlv:book,
    AUTHOR= "W. J. LeVeque",
    TITLE = "Topics in Number Theory ",
    PUBLISHER = "Addison-Wesley",
    YEAR = "1956",
    VOLUME = 2,
    )
```